# How to combine pwd with ls and grep

Tags: linux, file, terminal, directory, ls

Let's say that there are several directories and within them are several different files and I want to find a particular file location within all these directories.

How do you use `pwd` with `ls -laR | grep xyz`  so that I get to know the file location based on the size within all the directories and don't have to search each one of them after finding out that the file is present somewhere in these directories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use find with size as filter:

This example will find files larger than 3k in size:

```
find /path -size +3k
```

- c: bytes
- k: Kilobytes
- M: Megabytes
- G: Gigabytes

Answer (score 1):

I think the `find` command is what you are looking for.
To recursively search all files that are larger than `1k` bytes on `/home/my-path`:

```
find /home/my-path -size +1k
```

To better understand how to use find, and its size parameter (and others), see `man find`.

I'm not sure I fully understood what you meant, but I think the `find` command is what you are looking for.

To recursively search a file called `foo.txt` in the directory `/home/my-path`:

```
find /home/my-path -name foo.txt
```

If you don't exactly know the name of the file you could use wildcards (for example, `foo*.txt` if the file name starts with `foo` and ends with `.txt`).

If you still can't find your file, you can remove the `-name` parameter and pipe the output to `grep`.

Comment: Thank you but is there any way that I can find the location of this file by using the file size and if I did not know the name?

Since the file I am searching has a unique size compared to other files and when I `ls -laR | grep 1033` i see I have found the file but I don't know the location and when I use find to find it I got several other files within other directories.

I am sorry if i am not making sense

Comment: I didn't realize your search is based on size. I will edit my answer